# Selecting TOP @Number From "Group"

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

I think my attempt of wording this is going to be more difficult than sharing the code; However...
Firstly, I'm using SQL Server and extracting information from SAP B1.

I'm trying to generate a CSV file from my SQL Dataset to import into a logistics solution.

| OrderNo | NumberOfItems | ItemNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2 | 1 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2 |
| 45678 | 3 | 1 |
| 45678 | 3 | 2 |
| 45678 | 3 | 3 |

Using the above table, Order number 12345 would be a TOP 2 function, Order number 45678 would be a TOP 3 function.

The @TOPNUMBER will be pulled from an invoice within SAP so it will be dynamic for each Order number.

When I've writte my query I have performed an inner join using <> to bring through thousands of individual results, then filtering down using the TOP function. (which may have been my first mistake)

```
DECLARE @NUM AS INT = 3


SELECT TOP (@NUM) --Top Function to be replaced with "Number Of ITems"
T0.[DocNum] AS 'Order_No',
ISNULL(T0.NumAtCard,'') AS 'Cust_Ord_No',
 Convert(varchar,T0.DocDate,103) AS 'Order_Date',
  'Delivery' AS 'Order_Type',
  T0.CardName as 'Del_Name',
  ISNULL(T12.buIldingS,'') AS 'Del_Addr_1',
  ISNULL(T12.BlockS,'') AS 'Del_Addr_2',
  ISNULL(T12.StreetS,'') AS 'Del_Addr_3',
  ISNULL(T12.CityS,'') AS 'Del_Town',
  ISNULL(T12.CountyS,'') AS 'Del_County',
  ISNULL(T12.ZipCodeS,'') AS 'Postal_code', 
  ISNULL(T12.CountryS,'') AS 'Ctry_Code',
  ISNULL(t5.Tel1,'') AS 'Contact_Tel_1', 
  ISNULL(T5.Tel2,'') AS 'Contact_Tel_2',
  ISNULL(T5.Cellolar,'') AS 'Contat_Tel_Mob',
  ISNULL(T5.E_mailL,'') AS 'Contact_Email',
  ISNULL(T0.Comments,'') AS 'Order_Notes',
  '00:05' AS 'Unload_Time',
  '' AS 'Delivery_Method',
   convert(varchar,DateAdd(Day,-7,GETDATE()),103) AS 'Required_Date',
  ISNULL('10:00','') AS 'Required_Time_F', ---- Field to be created in sap
  ISNULL('16:00','') AS 'Required_Time_T', ---- Field to be created in sap
  Concat('Item ',Format(T1.DocEntry,'000')) as 'Item_Code',
  Concat('Item ',Format(T1.DocEntry,'000'),' Of ',FORMAT(@NUM,'000')) as 'Item_Desc',
  Concat(T0.DocNum,Format(T1.DocEntry,'000'),FORMAT(@NUM,'000')) AS 'package_id',
  '1' AS Item_Qty,
  T0.Weight/@NUM AS 'Item_Wgt',
  '' AS 'Item_Cube',
  convert(varchar,DateAdd(Day,-7,GETDATE()),103) AS 'Item_OnHand_Date'


 

  FROM OINV T0 INNER JOIN INV12 T12 ON T0.DocEntry = T12.DocEntry INNER JOIN OCPR T5 ON T5.[CntctCode] = T0.[CntctCode] INNER JOIN ORDR T1 ON T1.DocNum <> T0.DocEntry

  
  WHERE T0.DocNum > '1647674' AND T0.TrnspCode = 1

  ORDER BY T1.DocEntry
```

This code worked perfectly when I was using   `WHERE T0.DocNum = '1647674' AND T0.TrnspCode = 1`. As soon as I've changed it to a where clause with multiple DocNums it's falling flat on its face.

I'm thinking the easier option may be around me removing the `Select Top` and the Inner join on ORDR and OINV, and using my @NUM variable (from each document) to only actually give me the required number of lines instead of creating lots and filtering it down?

Any help will be appreciated as it took me a good couple of hours to get this to export in a format in which the CSV file takes with no issues!

---- EDIT ---- Update on the code, i think i've got somewhere close by tweaking a few things, i've actually changed the <> join on the ordr table, to a <= join relating to the variable i'm declaring..

I've ditched the variable number, and replaced it with a dynamic field within SAP.

```
SELECT 
T0.[DocNum] AS 'Order_No',
ISNULL(T0.NumAtCard,'') AS 'Cust_Ord_No',
 Convert(varchar,T0.DocDate,103) AS 'Order_Date',
  'Delivery' AS 'Order_Type',
  T0.CardName as 'Del_Name',
  ISNULL(T12.buIldingS,'') AS 'Del_Addr_1',
  ISNULL(T12.BlockS,'') AS 'Del_Addr_2',
  ISNULL(T12.StreetS,'') AS 'Del_Addr_3',
  ISNULL(T12.CityS,'') AS 'Del_Town',
  ISNULL(T12.CountyS,'') AS 'Del_County',
  ISNULL(T12.ZipCodeS,'') AS 'Postal_code', 
  ISNULL(T12.CountryS,'') AS 'Ctry_Code',
  ISNULL(t5.Tel1,'') AS 'Contact_Tel_1', 
  ISNULL(T5.Tel2,'') AS 'Contact_Tel_2',
  ISNULL(T5.Cellolar,'') AS 'Contat_Tel_Mob',
  ISNULL(T5.E_mailL,'') AS 'Contact_Email',
  ISNULL(T0.Comments,'') AS 'Order_Notes',
  '00:05' AS 'Unload_Time',
  '' AS 'Delivery_Method',
   convert(varchar,DateAdd(Day,-7,GETDATE()),103) AS 'Required_Date',
  ISNULL('10:00','') AS 'Required_Time_F', ---- Field to be created in sap
  ISNULL('16:00','') AS 'Required_Time_T', ---- Field to be created in sap
  Concat('Item ',Format(T1.DocEntry,'000')) as 'Item_Code',
  Concat('Item ',Format(T1.DocEntry,'000'),' Of ',FORMAT(T0.U_PACKQTY,'000')) as 'Item_Desc',
  Concat(T0.DocNum,Format(T1.DocEntry,'000'),FORMAT(T0.U_PACKQTY,'000')) AS 'package_id',
  '1' AS Item_Qty,
  T0.Weight/T0.U_PACKQTY AS 'Item_Wgt',
  '' AS 'Item_Cube',
  convert(varchar,DateAdd(Day,-7,GETDATE()),103) AS 'Item_OnHand_Date'--,

  FROM OINV T0 INNER JOIN INV12 T12 ON T0.DocEntry = T12.DocEntry INNER JOIN OCPR T5 ON T5.[CntctCode] = T0.[CntctCode] INNER JOIN ORDR T1 ON T1.DocEntry <= T0.U_PACKQTY

  
  WHERE T0.DocNum IN ('1647775','1647777','1647778')
```

The `WHERE T0.DocNum IN`  will be replaced with another where clause to look for "Van Delivery" transport types, and DocNum which will be greater than previously exported DocNum, this will probably be by inserting the "MAX" DocNum into a table at the time i export it, and then using this "MAX" Docnum as a  "Min" value in my where clause, so this should always look for new orders only. (I think!)

Comment: Why not get the value of `NumberOfItems` from your table and put the value into your variable `@NUM`?

Comment: When i do use this value NumberOfItems I end up with a TOP 1, or a TOP5 Query above the whole dataset,. I actually need my dataset to return 3 of one group, 5 of another group, 42 of another group etc..

Comment: Oh, then `TOP` *isn't* what you want. Use a CTE to number the rows, and then a `WHERE` to ensure the value is less than or equal to the number of rows you want.

Comment: Completely confused: why would you use `top` here at all? Why not a normal join, why do you need to "limit" the number of items? Perhaps you want a windowed `COUNT(*) OVER (...`?

Comment: Hi Charlieface; 
Basically what I need to do is create a spreadsheet with multiple lines for each order based on a variable defined by the warehouse. (the individual fields don't actually exist in the database) They are calculated based on the variable.

For example, Order 1 would have 3 lines on, so I need to enter Order Number 3 times in the spreadsheet. (The ordr table has a DocEntry ranging from 1 through to 99999, so if i join on this table, i can use the "DocEntry" as part of my unique prefix (parcel number 1 of 3, 2 of 3 etc).

Comment: Morning Larnu;
Would this essentially give me... the following? If so i'll look how to do it as it's not something i'm familiar with yet!

Order No 001 | Package 1 of 3
Order No 001 | Package 2 of 3
Order No 001 | Package 3 of 3
Order No 002 | Package 1 of 1
Order No 003 | Package 1 of 2
Order No 003 | Package 2 of 2

Answer (score 0):

I think DocNum is of type   varchar